# Filling colors in an imported image in Flash

Tags: flash

I'm trying to make a very simple game in Flash. I have a map where you can see only the borders of the states. I want to make every state a symbol. Can I somehow fill it with different colors? Using paint bucket doesn't work...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't use the paint bucket because it is a flat image.

Try dragging the image to the stage and then 'break it apart' (CTRL+B on a PC) so that it turns into an editable bitmap. You might then be able to use your paint bucket on it or at least delete areas from it.

Alternatively, you could either trace over the map in flash, and then use the paint bucket to fill the areas. This solution might be easier for creating your individual state symbols.

Comment: No problem :) Out of curiosity, which method did you use?